# Android: inter-activity notifications

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I guess my GIS foo isn't strong today as this seems pretty basic but I just can't find the answer I'm looking for. At any rate, I have one Android activity that needs to notify another (running) activity that something interesting has happened. I don't even need to pass any data but it would be nice to know how. Those familiar with iOS will no doubt recall the NSNotificationCenter object. What is the best way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether this is the best way, but you could send an intent, and set up the second activity so it can receive that intent (done in the AndroidManifest.xml file) and implement onHandleIntent(..). This might cause problems unless you use the "clear top" or similar flags. Should be some decent examples of this on the [Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Another alternative would be to use an interface, which is detailed pretty well [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Comment: I must be missing something. I know how to pass an intent when I start up an activity but I can't figure out how to pass an intent to an activity that's running. As best I can tell onHandleIntent() is not in the Activity class, so I would have to extend something other than an Activity.

Comment: Sorry, my error. The actual method is onNewIntent(..), which gets called when you use the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP". Basically, if there is a running instance of your activity, it will get pulled to the top of the stack, and onNewIntent(..) will be called. In this method, do whatever you need to with the Intent.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use an Intent to inform another activity.

[Intent | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)